# Exception received during connection with S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been trying to connect with amazon s3 using java. I have registered on amazon console and have the credentials. But when I run a code continuosly getting error on line:

```
AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);

Exception received:- *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<clinit>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:57)
    at bucket_conn.main(bucket_conn.java:25)*
```

I have imported all the important jar files. Then what exactly I am missing. For Now, just creating connection and fetching the buckets.

```
    String awsAccessKey = "*** access key ***";
    String awsSecretKey = "*** secret key ***";
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
    AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
    for (Bucket bucket : s3client.listBuckets()) {
        System.out.println("Bucket Name - " + bucket.getName());
    }



 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
at com.amazonaws.util.json.Jackson.<clinit>(Jackson.java:32)
at com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig.loadfrom(InternalConfig.java:232)
at com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig.load(InternalConfig.java:249)
at com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig$Factory.<clinit>(InternalConfig.java:284)
at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.userAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:139)
at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.initializeUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:134)
at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.getUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:95)
at com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration.<clinit>(ClientConfiguration.java:42)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:347)
at bucket_conn.main(bucket_conn.java:25)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss `commons-logging.jar` in your classpath. Download it and add it to your classpath.

UPDATE:
Now you miss `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jar`. Download it and add it to your classpath.

Comment: Thanks for the response . As u told, I have used commons-logging.1.1.1 jar but still getting exceptions.

Comment: @priya Same exception?

Comment: No this time its different. I am editing it in my question itself

Comment: @priya have changed my answer.

Comment: Sir I did it and exception increased again

Comment: @priya same exception?

Comment: No Sir each time i am getting new exceptions. I have added 3 more jar files in my project. Still the Exception exist